# iWebKit Framework windows phone topbar trasparent

Tags: iwebkit

Hello I've an App made with iwebkit framework 5,04 that work good with IOS and Android. The problem is that with Visual Studio  when I try the App with the simulator the topbar is trasparent, that an error because with the same code in IOS and Android is Black.

Any idea ?

Paolo

Answer (score 0):

iwebkit is built for the webkit rendering engine whereas visual studio probably uses trident which does not display the gradient top bar. It is made using a webkit specific property.

It is certainly possible to add the right css properties for it to work with IE, but you should code in VS but test in chrome/safari for it to show up right.